# Add vertices to an object that's being rendered

Tags: three.js

Being new to three.js I've dived into editing lines and vertices to see what's possible. Right now I'm creating my own empty geometry (`vertObj`), and adding a few vertices to it initially.

When it's rendered, I can see the vertices.

I would like to keep adding vertices over time (via `vertObj.vertices.push`) and to make the modification possible in render loop, I've set

```
vertObj.dynamic = true;
vertObj.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

however this does not change anything, I do not see the newly added points being rendered.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you rendering them? Point are not rendered visibly as part of a geometry.

Comment: THREE.LineBasicMaterial

Comment: Are you using a `THREE.Mesh` or a `THREE.Line` to render your geometry? Can you post a working example (preferrably a jsfiddle) that shows the problem?